# Python Turtle - Disable Window Resize

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Is there a way to disable the window resizing in the Turtle module?
E.G - Disable the maximize and minimize button and disable the ability to drag the window out or in. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's another way of doing it which is a little more 'hacky' but works well for projects that are already written using `TurtleScreen` and not a `RawTurtle`. It is actually a one-liner:

```py
screen = turtle.Screen()
# ...
screen.cv._rootwindow.resizable(False, False)
```

This accesses the root window of the scrollable canvas object that `turtle` creates and calls the `resizable` method on it. This is not documented, though - so it might produce unexpected behavior.

As a general remark: Whenever you want to use functionality of `tkinter` in a `turtle` program and you cannot find a `turtle` method for it - just check [`turtle`'s sources](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/turtle.py), figure out how `turtle` abstracts away the `tkinter` object (like the `canvas` in this case) and use the appropriate method on that object directly. Probably doesn't work all the time - but mostly you'll be able to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Python turtle is built atop tkinter.  When you run the turtle module *standalone*, it creates a tkinter window, layers it with a scrollable canvas and wraps in a screen object that provides lots of niceties for working with the turtle.  But you can instead run the turtle module *embedded* i.e. build whatever kind of tkinter window you want and run turtle inside it.

Here's a very simple example of a window with a turtle drawing that's not resizeable:

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import RawTurtle

root = Tk()
root.resizable(False, False)

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

turtle = RawTurtle(canvas)

turtle.circle(10)

root.mainloop()
```