# Disable fullscreen mode in Turtle

Tags: python, python-turtle

I'm a Python beginner and I'm trying to make a simple SNAKE GAME using the Turtle module. I'm making it with specific dimensions and the game goes weird when its put in full screen. The snake stays stuck inside a frame. Please give ideas of how I can block the fullscreen option in Turtle-python so that the game run smoothly.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please expand to some code of your game?

Comment: gameWin = turtle.Screen()
  gameWin.title("Snake game")
  gameWin.setup(width=600, height=600)
  gameWin.bgcolor("cyan")
  gameWin.tracer(0)

  food = turtle.Turtle()
  food.shape("circle")
  food.penup()
  food.goto(random.randint(-250, 230), random.randint(-250, 230))

if head.distance(food) < 20:
     food.goto(x, y)
     winsound.Beep(1000, 100)
     new_segment = turtle.Turtle()
     new_segment.shape("square")
     new_segment.color("maroon")
     new_segment.speed(0)
     new_segment.penup()

     segments.append(new_segment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most times when we want to do something to the window that turtle has no handle onto, we need to drop down to the tkinter underpinnings.  There are a couple of ways to go about this. In *standalone* turtle, we can use undocumented fields of turtle objects to access tkinter objects.  But if we want additional tkinter features like menus, we might instead make it a tkinter program with turtle graphics *embedded* in a canvas.

Here's the standalone approach, poking at the tkinter underpinnings:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen._root.resizable(False, False)  # drop down to tkinter

turtle = Turtle()

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-100)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.circle(100)

screen.mainloop()
```

This window should be locked to 600 by 600 and resist any change.  For the embedded approach, see [this answer about disabling turtle window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53438266/5771269).

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot! Now the fullscreen mode is blocked and the game runs smoothly!

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to "censor" out the extra stuff, maybe like this, with a function for a rectangle, and a function to make the background:

```
screenHeight = 800
screenWidth = 800

turtle.setup(screenWidth, screenHeight)

def rect(x,y,width,height,color="white"):
    go(x, y, t, 0, False)
    t.fillcolor(color)
    t.begin_fill()
    t.setx(x+width)
    t.sety(y+height)
    t.setx(x)
    t.sety(y)
    t.end_fill()

def menu():
    rect(0-(s.window_width()/2+5), 0-(s.window_height()/2+5), s.window_width()+10, s.window_height()+10, "gray")
    rect(-400, -400, 800, 800, "black")
    rect(-400, 300, 800, 100, "#101010")
```

You can change the values of `screenHeight` and `screenWidth` to change the original size of the turtle window.

FYI: t is the turtle, and s is the screen.

Comment: I had difficulty getting this code to do *anything* and certainly not what the OP desiries.